# Use ARKit detect phone moving trail and distance

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I want log phone moving trail and distance .

since we can use ARKit measure real world objects.

```
func distance(from vector: SCNVector3) -> Float {
    let distanceX = self.x - vector.x
    let distanceY = self.y - vector.y
    let distanceZ = self.z - vector.z

    return sqrtf( (distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY) + (distanceZ * distanceZ))
}
```

i can get distance between 2 SCNVector3 .

but i don't know how to log phone's current SCNVector3 in AR Scene

is it possible use ARKit measure phone move distance and moving trail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your ARSession,  the camera is located at 0,0,0 and it moves as you move the phone.  So if you want to know how far the phone is from its original position, just look at the translation portion of the camera transform matrix for the current frame:

```
frame.camera.transform
```

the x y and z translation components are in [`m41`, `m42` and `m43`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmatrix4) respectively.  See the [apple core animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW18) docs for more on matrices if you are not familiar with the math.

Comment: Yep. And to get a "moving trail", you'll need to record these values as they change over time.

Comment: thank u very much!  SCNVector3Make(transform.columns.3.x, transform.columns.3.y, transform.columns.3.z) , is this correct for  camera.transform to SCNVector3?